# Why does Krusader add a ^@ to all Useractions when running in the embedded terminal only?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, prompt, input

It looks like the Krusader File Manager appends a ^@ character (which is CTRL-@, that is a null char) every time it runs a Useraction but only if it's run in the embedded terminal. This then leads that character to be leaked to an eventual prompt that might be displayed at the beginning of the running of the Useraction, example: (for a Useraction set to `sudo -i muon`)

```
$ ^C
(cd '/tmp' && (sudo -i muon))
^@$ (cd '/tmp' && (sudo -i muon))
[sudo] password for root: *
```

As you can see on the third line there is a ^@ which is then spilled into the sudo prompt (I enabled a setting to display asterisks for each char typed, and don't worry about the -i flag or the fact that it asks for root instead of user).

It's worth noting that when the Useraction is set to run in a full terminal, the spill doesn't happen.

Does anybody know how to get rid of this spill in the embedded terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was causing it but upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04 made the issue go away.